# Elementor dynamic tags get post ID

Tags: elementor

In an **some Elementor widget > Link > Dynamic tags** I want to **get the post ID** (of product), is it possible?
In the Dynamic tags I see only one possible option throught I can get the ID, its Post custom field, Yes I know its for **custom fields**, but I want to try to consider the post ID as a custom field one too, so in the key field I tryed to input 'post' or 'post_id' or 'id', but nothing returned, maybe its should be another full taxonomy name for the post ID?
I couldn't find any information about it anywhere on the web.

[image]
[image]
[image]